# how to display an icon with a name (as an object) in a checked list box using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, icons

I am trying to add the icons along with a name to the checked list. tried passing it as an object , with icon picked up from the exe and the name hard coded but the problem is I am not able to see the icon and the name .

```
    public class ModuleOption
    {
        private readonly string _name;
        public string name  { get { return _name; } }

        private readonly Icon _icon;
        public Icon Icon { get { return _icon; } }

        public ModuleOption(string name, Icon icon)
        {

            _name = name;
            _icon = icon;
        }

    }
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643824/images-next-to-the-checkbox-in-checkedlistbox & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-sharp-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box

Comment: i went through the article and tried implemented the code , but its bit confusing , i didn't understand the fact  of why the image list is used , bit explanation would help